# Why in a pandas DataFrame with a MultiIndex columns of one level indexing behaves differently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

Using the example from `pandas` docs found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html), the following indexing works perfectly, the result being a `pd.Series`:

```
import pandas as pd
tuples = [(1, 'red'), (1, 'blue'),
          (2, 'red'), (2, 'blue')]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=('number', 'color'))
asdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=[0, 1])
asdf.loc[:, (1, 'red')]
```

but if I change the code a little bit, eliminating one level, the same indexing does not work:

```
import pandas as pd
tuples = [(1,), (2,)]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['number'])
asdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=[0, 1])
asdf.loc[:, (1,)]

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-d55399a979fa> in <module>
----> 1 asdf.loc[:, (1,)]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1760                 except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1761                     pass
-> 1762             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1763         else:
   1764             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1270     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: Tuple):
   1271         try:
-> 1272             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
   1273         except IndexingError:
   1274             pass

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_lowerdim(self, tup)
   1371         # we may have a nested tuples indexer here
   1372         if self._is_nested_tuple_indexer(tup):
-> 1373             return self._getitem_nested_tuple(tup)
   1374 
   1375         # we maybe be using a tuple to represent multiple dimensions here

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_nested_tuple(self, tup)
   1451 
   1452             current_ndim = obj.ndim
-> 1453             obj = getattr(obj, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=axis)
   1454             axis += 1
   1455 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1963         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1964         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1965         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1966 
   1967 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_label(self, label, axis)
    620             # see GH5667
    621             return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
--> 622         elif isinstance(label, tuple) and isinstance(label[axis], slice):
    623             raise IndexingError("no slices here, handle elsewhere")
    624 

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Furthermore, indexing it as `asdf.loc[:, 1]` throws a `TypeError`, and further still, indexing it as `asdf.loc[:, ((1,),)]` works, but the result is a `pd.DataFrame`, not a `pd.Series`!

Why does this happen? Thank you very much in advance!

P.S.: I'm interested in "abstracting" my code from these kind of issues (one level vs. multiple levels in a `pd.DataFrame.columns`). In the company where I work sometimes we get client data where multiple levels are needed, but other times only one level is needed.

Comment: I don't know what `ng.` is ....   both work the same for me if I remove `ng.`

Comment: @RobRaymond sorry, that was a leftover code. I've just edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: `asdf.loc[:, (1,)]` works fine for me in version 1.1.0

Comment: @RichieV yes, it works fine! I'll have to update `pandas`, I'm currently on version `v1.0.3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated your version of pandas? In `pandas v1.1.0`, you can index with one level as you have done, and slicing returns a `pd.Series`

```
import pandas as pd
tuples = [(1,), (2,)]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['number'])
asdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=[0, 1])
asdf.loc[:, (1,)]
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
```

Comment: This! This is what I've been looking for! Thanks! Yes, I should update `pandas`, my current version is `v1.0.3`.